# How to structure a Knockout.js application that uses multiple independent views?

Tags: architecture, knockout.js, template-engine

It's quite clear to me how to use Knockout.js if you have *one* view.

How do I structure an application if I have multiple views that are independent of each other? I can imagine that I should have on view model per view (of course, since this is the meaning of a *view* model), but how do I split the HTML files into components?

E.g., I'd like to have HTML snippets each in its own file for defining views, and the `index.html` only has placeholders for where to add these views.

I can not imagine that Knockout.js does not support this, but all the examples I found so far always were just one view (as the samples of [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/) are).

How do I break one big HTML file into multiple files, one for each view, and then combine them using Knockout.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, that's easy. [`applyBindings`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) method in Knockout JS accepts an optional DOM element as a second parameter. So in your case you can do something like:

```
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, 
    document.getElementById('myModuleWrapperDiv'));
ko.applyBindings(otherViewModel, 
    document.getElementById('otherModuleWrapperDiv'));
```

The only catch is that you won't be able to mix and match bindings from two view models in a single DOM sub-tree. For example this markup would work:

```
<div id="myModuleWrapperDiv">
    ...
</div>
<div id="otherModuleWrapperDiv">
    ...
</div>
```

This, however, wouldn't:

```
<div id="myModuleWrapperDiv">
    ...
    <div id="otherModuleWrapperDiv">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Here's how I do widgets with Knockout. Please note, that in 95% of the cases it's totally fine to simply load a template and apply bindings to it. However, if you need a *packaged* widget (i.e. something that you would release as a separate component) the best way to go is to wrap it in a custom binding. Angular JS promotes a similar approach with its directives.

1. Design markup for your widget as a document fragment. You can do it whatever you want: simple bit of HTML, a placeholder `div` with all rendering and interaction done in JavaScript - everything will do.
2. Design a view model for your template. Think of the data that might be required for your widget to render and operate and build your model according to that.
3. Create a custom binding for your widget. The simplest thing would be having it on a placeholder `div` element.

   a. Your `init` method should load the template and apply bindings of your internal widget view model to it. After bindings got applied you can append the resulting document fragment to a placeholder `div`.

   b. Your update method should change the state of your inner view model based on the values provided via custom binding attribute parameters.

Comment: This does still require that I have everything in a single HTML file. How do I load HTML snippets (without doing it manually, of course)?

Comment: @GoloRoden looks like you and I are thinking along similar lines today. Part of your answer is in [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449522/external-templates-and-el-with-knockout-and-requirejs) but it sounds like we are looking at the same basic issue.

Comment: Haha, looks like that :-)!